# How to change line thickness of a line (implicit_plot) in maxima [v5.44]?

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

I want to change the line width of a plot.

The `[style, [lines, 8, 1]]` option does not change the thickness. why is that?

I'm just typing it like so:

```
wximplicit_plot(y^2 = 4*(1/8)*x,  [x, -5, 10],[y, -10, 10], [yx_ratio, 1], [xtics, -4, 1, 10], [ytics, -10, 1, 10], [style, [lines, 8, 1]]);
```

Comment: Looks like there is a bug in implicit_plot. The way plotting options are handled was changed not too long ago and implicit_plot wasn't updated. I'll try to work on that in the near future, but as a work around, consider trying contour_plot instead. I guess for something exactly equivalent, you'll want only the contour equal to zero. Not sure if the documentation tells how to do that.

Comment: I'll file a bug report about implicit_plot, but you can try this instead: `wxdraw2d(line_width = 8, implicit(y^2 = 4*(1/8)*x, x, -5, 10, y, -10, 10))`.

Comment: For the record I've created a bug report for this: https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/bugs/3751/